# Android, SQLite: no such table exception in attached database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

I am getting "no such table" exception when trying to copy data into the attached database (`db`) encrypted with SQLCipher from plain database (`source`).

```
    StringBuilder attachDatabase = new StringBuilder();
    attachDatabase.append("ATTACH DATABASE '").append(this.db.getPath()).
                    append("' as ").append(NEW_DB_ALIAS).
                    append(" KEY '").append("123").append("';");
    source.execSQL(attachDatabase.toString());

    StringBuilder copyTable = new StringBuilder();
    String table = "t1";
    copyTable.append("INSERT INTO ").append(NEW_DB_ALIAS).append(".").append(table).
                append(" SELECT * FROM ").append(table).append(";");
    db.execSQL(copyTable.toString());
```

Encrypted database is created and has the same scheme as un-encrypted one. What could be the problem?

Comment: No. Had to workaround it somehow - do not remember the details

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify what version of SQLCipher for Android you are using?  We recently released 1.0 of the libraries which you can get here: https://github.com/downloads/guardianproject/android-database-sqlcipher/SQLCipherForAndroid-SDK-0.0.6-FINAL.zip

I just ran through the following scenario where the new database file does not exist prior to execution and it works well.  Can you try doing this without creating the new database with schema first:

```
    String newKey = "foo";
    File newDatabasePath = getDatabasePath("new.db");
    String attachCommand = "ATTACH DATABASE ? as encrypted KEY ?";
    String createCommand = "create table encrypted.t1(a,b)";
    String insertCommand = "insert into encrypted.t1 SELECT * from t1";
    String detachCommand = "DETACH DATABASE encrypted";
    encryptedDatabase.execSQL(attachCommand, new Object[]{newDatabasePath.getAbsolutePath(), newKey});
    encryptedDatabase.execSQL(createCommand);
    encryptedDatabase.execSQL(insertCommand);
    encryptedDatabase.execSQL(detachCommand);
```

Comment: I am using SQLCipher for Android v1 (0.0.6-RC1)

Comment: Could you execute ".schema" command using sqlite3 of the SQLCipher build of SQLite on both databases?  This will help verify the two schemas are the same.

Comment: If you would prefer you could run the following through code to verify as well (substitute NEW_DB_ALIAS with your value):

    select * from sqlite_master;
    select * from NEW_DB_ALIAS.sqlite_master;